# MySQL Search Friends Query

Tags: php, mysql, join, search, mysqli

I have a **user** table:

```
user_id | firstname | last name | picUrl ...
    1        bob       smith       null  
    2        bobby     smith       null  
    3        rob       smithies    null
```

I also have a **friends** table:

```
friend1_id | friend2_id | status | date_established
      1          2        accepted   2018-02-06 10:23:01
      2          1        accepted   2018-02-06 10:23:01
```

I have a simple query to search for users based on the criteria ($searchString) and order them in terms of the "best" match:

```
$query = "SELECT user_id, firstname, lastname, picUrl, LOWER(CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname)) as fullname  
          FROM user
          WHERE LOWER(CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname)) LIKE LOWER('%" . $searchString . "%') AND user_id != '{$userId}'
          ORDER BY
             CASE WHEN fullname = LOWER('" . $searchString . "') THEN 0
                  WHEN fullname = LOWER('" . $searchString . "%') THEN 1
                  WHEN fullname = LOWER('%" . $searchString . "%') THEN 2
                  WHEN fullname = LOWER('%" . $searchString . "') THEN 3
                  ELSE 4
                END, fullname DESC
          LIMIT 5";
```

The query will ignore the current user:

```
user_id != '{$userId}'
```

because you can't add yourself as a friend.

How can I ignore/not display users that are already friends?

**Example**

I am user 1.

I search for "Smith".

=> I am user 1, so I am not
displayed.

=> User 2 is already my friend so they aren't displayed.

=> Just **Rob Smithies** is displayed.

Comment: What are you asking for here?  Do you want a list of users with whom some user is not already friends?

Comment: I want a list of users that match the search criteria but are also not already friends.

Comment: Your friends table is somewhat unclear. For instance, was the friendship request send by 'friend1' or 'friend2', and who accepted it? I would not call these 'friend1' and 'friend2', but 'sender_id' and 'receiver_id', or something along those lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add one more condition which match friends'ids. Change your query as below

```
$query = "SELECT user_id, firstname, lastname, picUrl, LOWER(CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname)) as fullname  
          FROM user
          WHERE LOWER(CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname)) LIKE LOWER('%" . $searchString . "%') AND (user_id != '{$userId}' AND user_id not in (SELECT friend1_id from friends where friend2_id = '{$userId}') AND user_id not in (SELECT friend2_id from friends where friend1_id = '{$userId}'))
          ORDER BY
             CASE WHEN fullname = LOWER('" . $searchString . "') THEN 0
                  WHEN fullname = LOWER('" . $searchString . "%') THEN 1
                  WHEN fullname = LOWER('%" . $searchString . "%') THEN 2
                  WHEN fullname = LOWER('%" . $searchString . "') THEN 3
                  ELSE 4
                END, fullname DESC
          LIMIT 5";
```

Comment: I got a SQL error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax near '' at line 11 ? Are closing parenthesis missing or something?

Comment: It runs but displayed everyone i.e. me and people already friended.

Comment: Yes this works, figured that out with some experimentation myself as I knew the code wasn't far off. Thanks.